# method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user ''@'RAHUL-PC' (using password: YES)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm asking again a part of question. ASP.NET connection with MySQL remote serve. I'm using Windows 7 as client and Windows 2012 as server. using following code :-

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.Common;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public partial class college_data : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

protected void ButtonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        //String DSN = "Data Source = win2012server.db.net; port = 3306; Initial Catalog = collegedata, UserId = rahul; password = rahul; sslmode = none";
        String DSN = "Data Source = win2012server.db.net; port = 3306; Database = collegedata, Uid = rahul; Pwd = rahul;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(DSN);

        conn.Open();
        if (conn != null)
        {
            String sql = "insert into studentdata values('" + TextBoxRollNo.Text.Trim() + "', '" + TextBoxStudentName.Text.Trim() + "' , '" + TextBoxFatherName.Text.Trim() + "'" +
                          "'" + TextBoxMotherName.Text.Trim() + "'";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = sql;

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            LabelDisplay.Text = "data saved";
        }
        else
        {
            LabelDisplay.Text = "connection not opened";
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> Authentication to host 'win2012server.db.net' for user '' using
> method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for
> user''@'RAHUL-PC' (using password: YES)

in point `conn.open()`. How to solve this error?

Comment: there was my silly mistake i forgot putting " ; " after database=collegedata

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to web.config file :

```
<siteMap> <providers> <remove name="MySqlSiteMapProvider"/> </providers> </siteMap>
```

Comment: Please read the comment in the question. Poster has already solved the question by himself. He was missing a semi-colon character.

Answer (score 0):

So I see at least one error:

You have a comma between "collegedata, Uid" and not a semicolon.

**your connection string:**

```
String DSN = "Data Source = win2012server.db.net; port = 3306; Database = collegedata, Uid = rahul; Pwd = rahul;";
```

**the correct string:**

```
String DSN = "Data Source = win2012server.db.net; port = 3306; Database = collegedata; Uid = rahul; Pwd = rahul;";
```

**what I would recommend is to remove the space:**

```
String DSN = "Data Source=win2012server.db.net;port=3306;Database=collegedata;Uid=rahul;Pwd=rahul;";
```